# Not enought argument for format string

Tags: python, format

```
print ("He's got %s eyes and %s hair.\n\
        His teeth are usually %s depending on the coffe.\n\
        if I add %d, %d, and %d I get %d." % (
          my_eyes, my_hair, my_age, my_teeth,
          my_height, my_weight, my_age + my_height + my_weight))
```

Error: Not enough argument for format string

Comment: print ("He's got %s eyes and %s hair.\n\
         ` His teeth are usually %s depending on the coffe.\n\ 
          if I add %d, %d, and %d I get %d."  %(my_eyes, my_hair, my_age, my_teeth, my_height, my_weight, my_age + my_height + my_weight))

Comment: Please reformat your question, state which language you use and the error you get.

Comment: i'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This templating system is very old. You have to keep tracking types of variables. It's very uncomfortable.

In your code you have third insertion `%s` which associates with variable `my_age`, which probably not string variable as `%s` expects.

If you swap `my_age, my_teeth` to `my_teeth, my_age` you will get what you expect.

May I suggest you new .format templating system?

```
template = ("He's got {} eyes and {} hair.\n"
            "His teeth are usually {} depending on the coffe.\n"
            "if I add {}, {}, and {} I get {}.")
values = (my_eyes, my_hair, my_teeth, my_age,
          my_height, my_weight, my_age + my_height + my_weight)
print(template.format(*values))
```